# Downloading SUPEE 8788 V1 after v2 was released

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-8788, magento1.9.2.4

I have installed the SUPEE 8788 V1 and now I need to revert the patch to install V2. **I don't have the v1 sh file and the Magento download page only lets you download V2 now?**

**Where can I download the v1 version?**

Answer (score 4):

Brent Peterson has an updated repo of all the patches you can find it here: https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches?files=1